# How to continuing filtering process after we covered the data

Tags: python

I want to filter the training set to cover the testing set. I have done it using code below:

def filter_trainset(trainsets, testset, feature_sets, epsilon=0.1):

```
covering_points = []
covering_features = []
origins = []

for test_point in testset:
    found = False
    for i, trainset in enumerate(trainsets):
        if found:
            break
        for j, train_point in enumerate(trainset):
            if abs(train_point - test_point) <= epsilon:
                covering_points.append(train_point)
                covering_features.append(feature_sets[i][j])
                origins.append(i)
                found = True
                break

return np.array(covering_points), np.array(covering_features), origins

FPDataParticipant1 = np.array([
    [3.3],
    [6.5],
    [1.1],
    [1.1],
    [0.5],
])

FPDataParticipant2 = np.array([
    [6.5],
    [6.5],
    [3.1],
    [3.3],
    [7.8],
])

FPDataParticipant3 = np.array([
    [3.2],
    [6.4],
    [1.2],
])


SIDataParticipant1= np.array([
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 78.0, 45.0, 0.0,],
    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 78.0, 45.0, 0.0,],
    [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 78.0, 45.0, 0.0,],
    [4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 78.0, 45.0, 0.0,],
    [5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 78.0, 45.0, 0.0,],
])

SIDataParticipant2= np.array([
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 83.0, 37.0,],
    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 83.0, 37.0,],
    [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 83.0, 37.0,],
    [4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 83.0, 37.0,],
    [5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 83.0, 37.0,],
])

SIDataParticipant3 = np.array([
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108.0, 115.0, 87.0,],
    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108.0, 115.0, 87.0,],
    [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108.0, 115.0, 87.0,],
])

X_trainset = [SIDataParticipant1,SIDataParticipant2]
X_testingset = SIDataParticipant3
y_Trainset = [FPDataParticipant1,FPDataParticipant2]
y_Testingset = FPDataParticipant3

new_y_Trainset, new_X_trainset, origins = filter_trainset(y_Trainset, y_Testingset, X_trainset, epsilon=0.1)

print("New train set is:")
origin_counts = defaultdict(int)
for point, feature, origin in zip(new_y_Trainset, new_X_trainset, origins):
    origin_name = f"Participant{origin + 1}"  
    origin_counts[origin_name] += 1

for participant, count in origin_counts.items():
    print(f"Total data from {participant}: {count}")
```

Results:

```
new_y_Trainset : 
 [[3.3]
 [6.5]
 [1.1]]
```

when new_X_trainset has covered y_Testingset the process will stop. how to keep it running to filter it until we exhaust the training set (no any more data match with the y_Testingset.

```
expeted results for new_y_Trainset is as below:
 [[3.3] from FPDataParticipant1
 [6.5] from FPDataParticipant1
 [1.1] from FPDataParticipant1
 [3.1] from FPDataParticipant2
 [6.5] from FPDataParticipant2
 [1.1] from FPDataParticipant1
 [3.3] from FPDataParticipant2
 [6.5] from FPDataParticipant2
  ]
```